# Compiling problem after adding databinding in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies, android-databinding

When I'm trying to compile my Android project using dataBinding ressouce, I get this error message

```
w: warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: 
'[android.databinding.artifactType, android.databinding.printEncodedErrors, 
android.databinding.minApi, android.databinding.isTestVariant, 
android.databinding.enableDebugLogs, android.databinding.sdkDir, 
android.databinding.bindingBuildFolder, android.databinding.enableForTests, 
android.databinding.modulePackage, kapt.kotlin.generated, 
android.databinding.generationalFileOutDir, android.databinding.xmlOutDir]'
```

In the app build.gradle:

```
android {
    dataBinding{
        enabled=true
}
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio and Android tools are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 
Android Studio 3.2.1
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using data binding with kotlin, you need to add this in your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.1" // this version must like com.android.tools.build:gradle version
}
```